# Como hago para que mi menú hamburguesa no se muestre junto a la X; solo con CSS

Tags: css3

Tengo el menú hamburguesa y funciona bien, desplegando la lista; pero están juntos los dos iconos
"fas fa-bars"  y
"fas fa-times"

Como hago para que se muestre solo uno por vez?  Debo hacerlo solo con CSS.
Copio parte del código de Html5 y del CSS3  con Sass
Hace poco he comenzado a aprender.
Muchas Gracias!!

```
 <div class="respmenu">
            <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
            <label for="hamburger">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </label>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#episodios">EPISODIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nosotros">NOSOTROS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#entrevistas">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#topicos">TÓPICOS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>


.respmenu{
        input{
          display:none;
        }

        input:checked ~ ul{
           display: block;}
        }
```

Comment: segun tu logica en que momento debe mostrarce cada uno??

Comment: Hola Francisco!  según mi lógica, cuando esta en display none la lista del menú deberia solo verse el icono del menú hamburguesa y cuando la lista está desplegada, debería verse solo el ícono de X, para cerrarla. Gracias por tu colaboración !

Comment: ese es el problema le estas poniendo el css al ok input en que momento se lo colocas al icono???

Comment: ahh, es cierto Francisco. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te hace falta colocarle el CSS tambien al input:

```
.respmenu{
        input{
          display:none;
        }

        input:checked ~ ul{
           display: block;
        }

        i{
          display:none;
        }
}
```

o si quieres alternar entre uno y el otro deberás trabajarlo con `javascript/jquery`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Francisco!

Comment: @EmilioOscarAlmeida si la respuesta resuelve el problema te sugiero marcarla como resuelta ya que eso te da puntos.